# Remove multiple headers from Seriesand keep just the first python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I am working on below Series but Series inculde multiple header. So ,when i am merging or concat it create issue. I want to remove the duplicated headers and make standard Series i.e one header and rest are values.

**Series(src1 and tgt1)**

```
#**src1**
0                                  src_clmn
0     C001
1        src_clmn
0    DAI0001
1    DAI0002
2    DA...
dtype: object

#**tgt1**
0                                  tgt_clmn
0     C001
1        tgt_clmn
0    DAI0001
1    DAI0002
2    DA...
```

**Expected output:**

```
     src_clmn
0     C001
1    DAI0001
2    DAI0002
3    DA...
dtype: object

   tgt_clmn
0     C001
1    DAI0001
2    DAI0002
3    DA...
dtype: object
```

Comment: How are created DataFrames?

Comment: What is `print (src1.columns)` ?

Comment: dataframe are created with below function. Reading data from sql and store in datafeame.``` def source_input(tablename,columnname,businesskey,multiplecolumn,wherecondition,enddate,loaddttm):
    global df1, src_clmn, src_input
    try:

        if src_input.iloc[0]['src_tgt_validation_type'] == "PK":
            sql = 'select ' + columnname + ' as src_clmn from ' + tablename + ' where ' + \
                  wherecondition + ' and ' + loaddttm + 'order by 1'
            df1 = pd.read_sql_query(sql, db_conn)
            return df1```

Comment: @jezrael, print (src1.columns) is Index(['src_clmn'], dtype='object')

Comment: @Alia what is `src1.head().to_dict()`?

Comment: @PandaKim, src1.head().to_dict() output is ``` {0:   src_clmn
0     C001, 1:     src_clmn
0    DAI0001
1    DAI0002
2    DAI0003
3    DAI0004
4    DAI0005
..       ...
495  DAI0496
496  DAI0497
497  DAI0498
498  DAI0499
499  DAI0500```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out values match first value of `Series`, create default index and last set `Series.name` by first value:

```
src1 = pd.Series(['src_clmn','C001','src_clmn','DAI0001','DAI0001'], index=[0,1,0,1,2])

out = src1[src1.ne(src1.iat[0])].reset_index(drop=True).rename(src1.iat[0])
    
print (out)
0       C001
1    DAI0001
2    DAI0001
Name: src_clmn, dtype: object
```

If need remove only first value and assign to `Series.name`:

```
src1 = pd.Series(['src_clmn','C001'], index=[0,1])
out = src1.iloc[1:].rename(src1.iat[0])
    
print (out)
1    C001
Name: src_clmn, dtype: object
```

EDIT: Converted to DataFrame:

```
src1 = pd.Series(['src_clmn','C001','src_clmn','DAI0001','DAI0001'], index=[0,1,0,1,2])

df = src1.to_frame(src1.iat[0])
print (df)
   src_clmn
0  src_clmn
1      C001
0  src_clmn
1   DAI0001
2   DAI0001

out = df[df.ne(df.columns).all(axis=1)].reset_index(drop=True)
print (out)
  src_clmn
0     C001
1  DAI0001
2  DAI0001
```

Comment: i am calling function like ``` src1 = src_input.apply(lambda x: source_input(x['schema_table'], x['column_name'],x['business_key_name'],x['select_column_names'],x['where_condition'],x['end_date'],x['load_dt_tm']), axis=1)```  .after this src1 become Series. Used above solution which you mentioned then it throw error ```AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'```

Comment: @Alia - Not understand, `print (src1.columns)` is `Index(['src_clmn'], dtype='object')` and now it is `Series`  with `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'` ?

Comment: @jezrael- my appologies , print (src1.columns) is giving ``` AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns' ``` .  ``` Index(['src_clmn'], dtype='object') ``` is source_input() output which i mentioned in very first comment.

Comment: @Alia - What is `print (src1.to_frame().columns)` ?

Comment: @ jezrael, output of ``` print (src1.to_frame().columns) ``` is ``` RangeIndex(start=0, stop=1, step=1) ```

Comment: @Alia - Answer was edited.

Comment: @jezrael- one question ``` src1 = pd.Series(['src_clmn','C001','src_clmn','DAI0001','DAI0001'], index=[0,1,0,1,2]) ``` you defined values manually but what happend in next run values will change only column name will be same .values will vary based on input .

Comment: @Alia - It is sample data. For each run need this solution - get out values with first value and assign back.

Comment: @jezrael- this is not giving expected output. column name removed and every time we cannot change the values manually.. is there another way to remove duplicate header from series. Thank you so much for your efforts :)

Comment: @Alia - So now `column name removed` ? How possible columns if working with `Series` - `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'` ?

Comment: @jezrael- i have converted src1 into dataframe . After that output of src1 like -```                                              0
0                                src_clmn
0     C001
1      src_clmn
0    DAI0001
1    DAI0002
2    DA...
typ <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> ```

Comment: @Alia - not understand, why? `df = out.to_frame()` cannot use?